# Python set difference of strings

Tags: python, string, set, set-difference

I encountered the below peculiar behaviour when creating difference of string sets in Python:

```
set(['a', 'b']) - set(['a'])   # results in {'b'} as expected
set(['a', 'b']) - set('a')     # results in {'b'} as expected
set(['a.', 'b']) - set(['a.']) # results in {'b'} as expected
set(['a.', 'b']) - set('a.')   # surprisingly results in {'a.', 'b'}!
```

Why is it that in the last case 'a.' is not subtracted from the set? Since the difference between the second and the fourth case is the dot, I reckon that is the culprit. Using double quotes gives the same behaviour.

Comment: `set('a.') = {'.', 'a'}`, so not sure I would call this behaviour surprising

Comment: Have you seen what `set('a.')` is? It's the set with the strings `'a'` and `'.'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your last set is interpreted as `{'a', '.'}`. So your set operation will not exclude `'a.'`

It's because set will iterate through the input, and the iteration over a string is by char.

Comment: Could you give me a clue why it is interpreted in such a way? It seems counterintuitive coming from Scala.

Comment: @bugfoot `for x in 'abc'` is reading the character `a, b, c` consequently. And for a list `['abc']` it's different because there's only one item.

Comment: It is turning the contents of the iterable into a set. If the iterable is a list, its creating a set from each element in the list. The same applies to a string @bugfoot

Comment: So its not the dot but any multi-character string... modified the title accordingly.

Comment: @bugfoot You can open an REPL and type `set('abc')` to help better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I see now, thanks @knh190 ... {'i', 't', 'e', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e', 's'}

Answer (score 4):

`set('a.')` interprets the string as a list of characters `['a','.]`, resulting in `{'.', 'a'}`

`set(['a.', 'b'])` interprets the list as `['a.', 'b']`, resulting in `{'a.', 'b'}`

Now when you take the set difference, the result is `{'a.', 'b'}` since the set difference of first and second set is the first set itself, as no common elements are present in the two sets.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

> difference(*others) . set - other - ...
>   Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others.

The behaviour can be seen as follows below more clearly

```
In [1]: set('a.')                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[1]: {'.', 'a'}

In [2]: set(['a.', 'b'])                                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: {'a.', 'b'}

In [3]: set(['a.', 'b']) -  set('a.')                                                                                                                                               
Out[3]: {'a.', 'b'}
```